# Is there any way to tell MATLAB to close/exit all open executables/MEX files?

Tags: windows, matlab

I am currently working on a project that uses MATLAB and MEX files.

I frequently make changes to the MEX source files for testing, and then go to replace these files with my newly-compiled ones.

However, Windows refuses to replace these files, as MATLAB currently has them "open", despite having quit the debugging process.

So my only option has been to completely close the MATLAB application, copy/replace the MEX files, and then re-open MATLAB.

This is a pain. Any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently running:

`clear all`

After quitting the debugging session each time works. I got it mixed up and thought `fclose('all')` was required, but that apparently is unnecessary.